# Timer in C# with different thread

Tags: c#

```
   static Timer _timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       _timer = new Timer(1000);
       _timer.Enabled = true;
       _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
        string strXMLComperator = @"D:\randomFiles\rand" + i + ".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(strXMLComperator))
        {
          StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(strXMLComperator, false, Encoding.UTF8);
          sWriter.Write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><catalog>dasd</catalog>");
          sWriter.Flush();
          sWriter.Close();
          sWriter.Dispose();
        }
      }
    }   



     private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
       //some code here
     }
```

i want to know will Main() Method add files when OnTimedEvent works or it will stop working  while timer_event finish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you haven't said which `Timer` class you're using, but assuming you're not using the Windows Forms timer, then yes: the `OnTimedEvent` method will be called in a different thread to the Main thread (a thread-pool thread, actually), so they'll run concurrently.

(Note that contrary to your question title, this isn't a different *process* - just a different *thread*.)

Comment: Really? OnTimedEvent() and Main() work in diffrent threads? it means that all will work correctly Main method will add files and the same time Timer will do somethink.  am usin  System.Timers.Timer

Comment: @AemLoviji: Yes... as per the documentation: "The Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread"